# Create Realm Object Singleton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

In my app, I have a RLMUser object which is a RLMObject.

How do I create a singleton to store that user in, and retrieve that RLMUser object using singletons?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not recommended to create singletons with Realm especially when dealing with threading. Hopefully the link Glenn shared helps

Comment: The link is only about singletons, not about Realm. Use it wiseley ;) PS I don't know anything about Realm, could you just tell me in short why a singleton is not recommended?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is an excellent tutorial from RayWenderlich for singletons (and other stuff)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: this does not answer the question